# Pythonic way of doing 'for these except myself'

Tags: oop, list, python

Basically, wondering what the best / most python-y way of doing this is;

```
class thing(collectionclass):
    for onething in super(collectionclass,listofthings):
        if onething != self:
            do something
```

This is obviously a very contrived example but hopefully the point is clear!

I was thinking of folding the whole thing up into a list comprehensions but wanted to communities opinion

Comment: The use case seems like a design error.  you've conflated the container and the items in the container.  Why can't this functionality be moved into the container and out of the item?

Comment: This seems like a mistake.  Why would a method of an object affect only *other* objects of the same type?  Why not have this code elsewhere, outside the object?

Comment: self does not seem to have meaning in this context, things would be different if you had put:

    class thing():
        def my_method(self,listofthings):
            for onething in listofthings:
                if onething != self:
                    do something

Comment: that's exactly what I was going to say... an instance of a class shouldn't have to know how to handle other instances of its type.

Comment: @calavera: and how you implement the composite pattern then? However, an instance having, as a data member, a container in which it is itself contained is rather weird.

Comment: @Andre: I suppose I was being pretty general.  But this is definitely bad design unless its just some simple static method on foo that takes a container of foo.  But it's obviously not since it's referencing self.  So if he's truly keeping a container of foo that includes self inside an instance of foo... shudder.

Comment: I apologise for the general crumminess of the example; listofthings in the actual implementation is coming from the parent and is not stored internally. Updating question to be a little clearer

Comment: @Andrew Bolster: "listofthings in the actual implementation is coming from the parent".  Why can't you make this `thing` method a part of the parent and simplify this design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). I would go verbose instead of clever.

```
class MyThing():
    def do_something_to_everyone_but_me(self, list_of_things)
        for one_thing in list_of_things:
            if one_thing is self:
                continue
            do_something_with(one_thing)
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd use

```
for onething in listofthings:
    if onething is self:
        continue
    # ...
```

to avoid one level of nesting. You could also use a generator expression:

```
for onething in (x for x in listofthings if x is not self):
    # ...
```

Also, S.Lott's comment.

Edit: Changed `==` to `is` as per @greggo's comment. Better not get object identity and equality confused!

Comment: "if onething is self" (things may be different instances and == may still be true).

Answer (score 1):

I say that the answer depends on the complexity of the `do something`. If it's simple, a list comprehension or a generator would be quite neat; if it's complex, what you have is nice and clear (if just a little verbose.)

Answer (score 0):

Either `continue` on `self`, or use a genex to exclude in the first place.

```
for onething in (x for x in listofthings if x != self):
  ...
```